# Bouncy Castle-encrypted payload comes broken from SAP PI

Tags: java, bouncycastle, sap-pi, sap-xi

### Issue

I am using Bouncy Castle java to encrypt files using PGP. The program is meant to run into SAP PI 7.0. When I run PI’s output (encrypted file) against the decryption program, I get an **empty decrypted file** with no error.

So, I tried to encrypt the same source file in Eclipse, using the same parameters. This time, I was able to decrypt the output correctly to **retrieve my original file**. Same code, same input.

At some point, I noticed that PI output is a few bytes shorter *(usually 32 bytes)* than Eclipse’s output. I think that’s the reason why the decryption output is empty without error. I have no idea what might be missing in the encrypted file as both PGP message have the same shape.

Any suggestion on how I can fix it? Is there a part of the PGP message that is missing? Do I miss a library or a configuration point in PI environment?

### Technical details

**Bouncy Castle**

- Version 1.47
- JDK: 1.3
- Jar downloadable at http://polydistortion.net/bc/download/: jce-jdk13-147.jar, bcpg-jdk13-147.jar

**Local environment**

- Java: 1.6.0_45
- Operating System: Windows 7 SP1
- JDK version: 1.3

**SAP PI environment**

- PI version: 7.0
- Java Runtime: Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (version=1.4.2_14-b05)
- Java Virtual Machine : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (version=1.4.2_14-b05)
- Operation System: Windows 2003 (version=5.2, arch=amd64)
- JDK version: 1.3

### DSA Key pair

**Public key**

> -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
>
> Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> mQGhBFUMSHMRBADrMi7kuXATsOdtvG2TBhe+U+SRp7fCEJKhd4Xs27HsNZ82c954
>   sHXiAXT1g6chdD+R8ZYWL8LQ2Jsu69YpzdRWgLkR4BK0mvKtrW84gVjRC9jgCgmw
>   VETvFU3b5wzJYOSX0xOhCQK7F8bptrNAhhmnR+cTfYnzRLnXlwTKG7lKBwCg8nbw
>   dccq7kyASZxbWz11d+3yvHEEAL8THYETkpsGu/AWN6P3ffl6qXpX7LLPnccrnSHT
>   M4MKuRVnRZUlBRAK4koWwkYgzmYNKcbJLk850814Im/Tl2+1+HpYPuX7Cp+Hqyo2
>   Y3VVZMA+1LlU+uXsMRQ6ce8GW7iuo31EVGxuSichgIb6G4k9zfR3J+IP3kiGeLcd
>   akZuA/jgGXGkCsPJwRXefIn79OyMMjGbb0FwLJLUat5M2XDoYr2AsZ6xKsybdJBM
>   XFbwOsn6yNqhcKgIHn1kA/WgwM6L4AQQrw2KN/kue/p+qmcws2SdBzlmIcLcWbw1
>   lQlrbp3UHxGW2oagv5myXBUElF1HOQaV7tYi2mYvRAW3P8oQtA50ZXN0QGdtYWls
>   LmNvbYhGBBMRAgAGBQJVDEh0AAoJEP9twmjt49AnCrgAnj/feW9MahLwrFgNyW6H
>   RpC0odESAJ0Tzy6Zs3AvhbMl8jHC/URS8i2P27kEDQRVDEh0EBAA///////////J
>   D9qiIWjCNMTGYouA3BzRKQJOCIpnzHQCC76mOxObIlFKCHmONATd75UZs806Qxsw
>   Kwpt8l8UN0/hNW1tUcJF5IW1dmJefsb0TELppjftawv/XLb0Brft7jhr+1qJn6Wu
>   nyQRfEsf5kkoZlHs5Fs9wgB8uKFjvwWY2kg2HFXTmmkWP6j9JM9fg2VdI9yjrZYc
>   YvNWIIVSu57VKQdwlpZtZww1Tkq8mATxdGwIyhghfDKQXkYuNs474553LBgOhgOb
>   J4Oi7Aeij7XFXfBvTFLJ3ivL9pVYFxg5lUl86pVq5RXSJhiY+gUQFXKOWoqqxC2t
>   MxcNBFB6M6hVIavfHLpk7PuFBFjb7wqK6nFXXQYMfbOXD4Wm4eTHq/WujNsJM9ce
>   jJTgSiVhnc7j0iYa0u5r8S/6BtmKCGTYdgJzPshqZFIfKxgXeyAMu+EXV3phXWx3
>   CYjAutlG4gjiT6B05asxQ9tb/OD9EI5LgtEgqSEIARpyPBKnh+bXiHGaEL26WyaZ
>   wycYavTiPBqUaDS2FQvaJYPpyirUTOjbu8LbBN6O+S6O/BQfvsqmKHxZR05rwF2Z
>   spZPoJDDoiM7oYZRW+ftH2EpcM7i16+4G912IXBIHNAGkSfVsFqpk7TqmI2P3cGG
>   /7fckKbAj030Nck0BjGZ//////////8AAgIQALb4lhJnxVfKtUBZTP65CtmiaMGM
>   7slmH2EEMd1WkgNMBawq2W9gEAkqgc8oSTC2BAjEdyV03pp/Q2TsbUHkVH4YnK/M
>   K3N4+hOrqMGfo8e1aptSFixmq6aXDozsQyMutAjg5sJOLdhW9dQN/mgC9EVNnWF/
>   Q/COB19QaX/ayyzQ8+IJUwwLU4vajZopYq9Gg6H9WksAFQWQOfuhrvf6rAzjSeSR
>   mjecXm+0Rk06waxP3ZvAgjqQGiQ+3PS6DSZNDpbT2x1j8Fl92m7hr5Bo5d73CGrl
>   Qeyh6VxEviSw2bLSLcQvvB+KYBCxY+6t445/r4ONRgFZPT8YlAnQv8fw+otkHjnE
>   fQZxVdb0rtMQ5uGVilLKSjOirjPKBApg5d3m0rOtpQvLyF4FzCxxM88aaeAP4Rfg
>   7JWcGx1zdk3SQKM9p9bZ/pvNFiorJPTLgw9j1+FnQasegnqJd8n6GetH+BnWDlBL
>   YnFwo9RDIkw5v+uG9ZzWQfSgVg3QrWoxQQ9kCs0ro89zLLitdkfXM9aQRJ/dhYKj
>   pJrLglgjGBDbG6Vv/JmxFdhe5bRRHBSFGkNfQQFTQ1//VyIPPZZtGOx317s4QmEo
>   RDxLHgH1fzr41LsXvX2PpbLHXxTpIY7J+pe6yZlmzeXLLKF0ZqXnjkg2MX2x/+Se
>   lJn8ufW3q8LgBCcqiEYEGBECAAYFAlUMSHUACgkQ/23CaO3j0CeVYACfcP5ocfsB
>   fCDlTfnmAv+CISHwpdcAn3TSeD6ftizjUcNBxQwnjqfKN3T8
>
> =CPWK
>
> -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

**Private key (password: “TestPass12345!”)**

> -----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
>
> Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> lQHoBFUMSHMRBADrMi7kuXATsOdtvG2TBhe+U+SRp7fCEJKhd4Xs27HsNZ82c954
>   sHXiAXT1g6chdD+R8ZYWL8LQ2Jsu69YpzdRWgLkR4BK0mvKtrW84gVjRC9jgCgmw
>   VETvFU3b5wzJYOSX0xOhCQK7F8bptrNAhhmnR+cTfYnzRLnXlwTKG7lKBwCg8nbw
>   dccq7kyASZxbWz11d+3yvHEEAL8THYETkpsGu/AWN6P3ffl6qXpX7LLPnccrnSHT
>   M4MKuRVnRZUlBRAK4koWwkYgzmYNKcbJLk850814Im/Tl2+1+HpYPuX7Cp+Hqyo2
>   Y3VVZMA+1LlU+uXsMRQ6ce8GW7iuo31EVGxuSichgIb6G4k9zfR3J+IP3kiGeLcd
>   akZuA/jgGXGkCsPJwRXefIn79OyMMjGbb0FwLJLUat5M2XDoYr2AsZ6xKsybdJBM
>   XFbwOsn6yNqhcKgIHn1kA/WgwM6L4AQQrw2KN/kue/p+qmcws2SdBzlmIcLcWbw1
>   lQlrbp3UHxGW2oagv5myXBUElF1HOQaV7tYi2mYvRAW3P8oQ/gkDAjEsU2VRQwZQ
>   YM1E4ZLx+XLpfEac9ewO5vxMJEEWnxym3T6xlTkWAQC/nlWr5tpvckYiQgr5F3hn
>   1lAW/Wu3UPvjA4a0DnRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tiEYEExECAAYFAlUMSHQACgkQ/23C
>   aO3j0CcKuACeP995b0xqEvCsWA3JbodGkLSh0RIAnRPPLpmzcC+FsyXyMcL9RFLy
>   LY/bnQZABFUMSHQQEAD//////////8kP2qIhaMI0xMZii4DcHNEpAk4IimfMdAIL
>   vqY7E5siUUoIeY40BN3vlRmzzTpDGzArCm3yXxQ3T+E1bW1RwkXkhbV2Yl5+xvRM
>   QummN+1rC/9ctvQGt+3uOGv7Womfpa6fJBF8Sx/mSShmUezkWz3CAHy4oWO/BZja
>   SDYcVdOaaRY/qP0kz1+DZV0j3KOtlhxi81YghVK7ntUpB3CWlm1nDDVOSryYBPF0
>   bAjKGCF8MpBeRi42zjvjnncsGA6GA5sng6LsB6KPtcVd8G9MUsneK8v2lVgXGDmV
>   SXzqlWrlFdImGJj6BRAVco5aiqrELa0zFw0EUHozqFUhq98cumTs+4UEWNvvCorq
>   cVddBgx9s5cPhabh5Mer9a6M2wkz1x6MlOBKJWGdzuPSJhrS7mvxL/oG2YoIZNh2
>   AnM+yGpkUh8rGBd7IAy74RdXemFdbHcJiMC62UbiCOJPoHTlqzFD21v84P0QjkuC
>   0SCpIQgBGnI8EqeH5teIcZoQvbpbJpnDJxhq9OI8GpRoNLYVC9olg+nKKtRM6Nu7
>   wtsE3o75Lo78FB++yqYofFlHTmvAXZmylk+gkMOiIzuhhlFb5+0fYSlwzuLXr7gb
>   3XYhcEgc0AaRJ9WwWqmTtOqYjY/dwYb/t9yQpsCPTfQ1yTQGMZn//////////wAC
>   AhAAtviWEmfFV8q1QFlM/rkK2aJowYzuyWYfYQQx3VaSA0wFrCrZb2AQCSqBzyhJ
>   MLYECMR3JXTemn9DZOxtQeRUfhicr8wrc3j6E6uowZ+jx7Vqm1IWLGarppcOjOxD
>   Iy60CODmwk4t2Fb11A3+aAL0RU2dYX9D8I4HX1Bpf9rLLNDz4glTDAtTi9qNmili
>   r0aDof1aSwAVBZA5+6Gu9/qsDONJ5JGaN5xeb7RGTTrBrE/dm8CCOpAaJD7c9LoN
>   Jk0OltPbHWPwWX3abuGvkGjl3vcIauVB7KHpXES+JLDZstItxC+8H4pgELFj7q3j
>   jn+vg41GAVk9PxiUCdC/x/D6i2QeOcR9BnFV1vSu0xDm4ZWKUspKM6KuM8oECmDl
>   3ebSs62lC8vIXgXMLHEzzxpp4A/hF+DslZwbHXN2TdJAoz2n1tn+m80WKisk9MuD
>   D2PX4WdBqx6Ceol3yfoZ60f4GdYOUEticXCj1EMiTDm/64b1nNZB9KBWDdCtajFB
>   D2QKzSujz3MsuK12R9cz1pBEn92FgqOkmsuCWCMYENsbpW/8mbEV2F7ltFEcFIUa
>   Q19BAVNDX/9XIg89lm0Y7HfXuzhCYShEPEseAfV/OvjUuxe9fY+lssdfFOkhjsn6
>   l7rJmWbN5cssoXRmpeeOSDYxfbH/5J6Umfy59berwuAEJyr+CQMCMSxTZVFDBlBg
>   sfC08oFwjbf2kp9qaHLORoOMbU/Fyjc343iR9Ifo0HJtyrA37/BW4XCJzs+Z8CeT
>   0Cf6f22oErofdyS4w3TaO+yGgmUJ75BSbqveAU/4DJsl3k+0vRSVgsphe3Nlh2P1
>   +8s9qtvIcRc27oSBDw2SG+rSTWEQrb9aJty6DekWHTjBXiCj6ZuZeJxDxJ3Vs967 Ty4q+PFRNynp9na9aXa7H2LbkwY/HaKibi63BMJsDZJT/q1vWd3ZpbCv1xhtUnk7
>   02nQurC8+L1/6xeoJv6/tCT0OcHkWf+Fem3FSATZUA2yy4JT1yK7KFNgNSRF5b+k
>   MLNiz4VmW+5ym31YqVguD9JmD02qkgX4U5ATLnwvGXFaW4JRsODbX7I/08tRgcUe
>   x+fURZwJF86rtfJxrCKJHWTd0GYb1/iZlRs0D6AZdlwKN3+6Dge/04d9g9BQ9giq
>   HOmXFk5jE22wTOzq9VUES6HzBHCpq32GxYdQ7/4ZTLbQpw3whPsHcAeNmidxsGyG
>   QmP/Xs757dnDsAmL9TQ1Ph1UftcxuPHiPIsMBM44VMglBacfOnEDCTl8hHiNOK1+
>   V+8sg5PBd2OTJVKC95Oe4NIgYo1MCNZhDRNCyut1h1eMHkcQZfCxXvPTOBDR7HXz
>   lcfHnxwkYQC3mSK5hMPT3IYSSihY6gRUrD62jj4w6X5HhAo5sRjcisT0lXYjtKx3
>   PDgfqHQU0CnmKqovVIwUuYYNn9aYM4hGBBgRAgAGBQJVDEh1AAoJEP9twmjt49An
>   lWAAn3D+aHH7AXwg5U355gL/giEh8KXXAJ900ng+n7Ys41HDQcUMJ46nyjd0/A==
>
> =kuac
>
> -----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

### Encrypted output

**Eclipse**

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> hQQOA0fjQmjVGrtrEA/+JTCsjY1frycHtMDeTPYfmsRX/nnVuTTvB2c9ZkK3GJq+
>   TF2kMXhG4xj8XO5c7DtIehKwIAMvvirpX456mnObGMUQMtguXvsCMuY766SmgRx6
>   GebHU0v166xkN/9ZmHBsQxti7P1qFAJe4XVAhNXb+odUGrnSPNfQY4gUvvP6DM7a
>   azaCQygElNfhBP26XODKD8h2xJqyNF9HodEmVevrhvBPQFZvAcA0KLFX1hvWG9Us
>   D4eOrZp0UL4KoabDtHcTvUILRqmgslX9oMMrEoPdEdkvWJTeZMf8Yf8S0aNoUtAB
>   Rpi49n2kTiQcX5x313stxSaP9mcmyKsMAlXn0BgnWUS/w4GGGB6GWki1OirHi2DG
>   3Q0LOMWlYrLinXq9C+3cHCSiBYhF6Z+D74L97YGNMtHPfZ6B/Q4B7B64RKJlmC/S
>   7k0aeyGSzYm35heBKifKs6gQiiW352HppJsOvgsZr+0/p8BIMZtgJReFnZ/plsz0
>   vB3aoDYkUtNJR+WpwRYUnS4YR7Ga5/uqQvrFUBuyvOQdfsZJeLxzG6geyefBi183
>   GskEMOWHTdU5uUgI2LGzCpp1hOJ5+O/KXdLUIF+r+Z/khp+qsJPVmxRRhAFuf0Uq
>   4outUwiq/cr0PJ9je3rcIpx6jku2FFzlf3CH6rVVrqU8jzHJOtrq5yKMsVLIJeQQ
>   AIUTlgkgXFzcl6P1fuo73uZBY047twIq1pe7rW2rKZW7V5eZNM+FPgBjZ0NFu19A
>   Ca9U5EobdNO2ZZxD4+ye+GKtGdKmQ6I3+B938tVnJYvRZwoc7oyKieO59oxuJGgG
>   UkIx34ivVojvovpk5mojGL0Ne1RPV3mP+88r/EHmEuyVYiwj6zN5TP6WecEBBxAY
>   EIJKae+GfArAW9fjIq+FRTNU6W3F5dhp3AasbUpIcS07exOzIy6zmhyUYchEFRWW
>   /tKQzXT42zZySPicVI5NkepOvCwRIaTU/VYL12bMN26bvbZRXYoONxbOXjywOCy8
>   Xf9Shr/Uf9PUc9P3H0rCflHxCe+KeVya3FDNhIJzyOkE0LAR3BXIdidSV64UBrkN
>   FBYZv4CAqzI5pyuGoK0Jfc5sCLVtPY06s9n/EocNQUmbRXCgOKv1dV9KSTByyR4J
>   j3wQ8Vh/iIPYiP352VSsql2IrYHPHaNT12BrgD1wu9ZD3+GKV33nbEiyPnsVbMLN
>   6PuMS7DnDyqQQIt5j5eg2sM3t9UTs938DDIFDp1hCVY6YBvPRgMCB4Gni54yxfc8
>   QKn++90yWR6Fu0pwnsD2WL6Pcqf3xD5r+ke+HG8FmYo8OwIkyLbHLCyacMvs6dhK
>   ZZnlFNvRteSLD1hw0o+MF6RoC9hhJYwOlfWGOBqEMjYf0lkB3O1rt6maKwNG1ljt
>   kG3lN0xRK5XMFPMmzlZfI2xj4vMLlN+06uNnir9QSWqszOL1aPhR511vr2bGj/Zx
>   +eSizjofZbU0p3wiR8D60s+9PeuE24XbOfsyCg==
>
> =/OMU
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----

**SAP PI**

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> hQQOA0fjQmjVGrtrEBAAh/d/hO+no+nonMzRJlLVnJeEcahzDTtCD9+aIljOsLIu
>   pUgyJ1VZTGe6heqJw4R88V96Yc1BxsW0SkvcNyZ5HCraRyt1yeNQE4e6BgFI7J53
>   nBBb1d8Qd07YIRpiOgqaVDgluLa7LXkFPjgmN2JEPXUSchtI73EEFYIxmeSwdyyY
>   wKRi3kjcZu/MK9NJ74InWviFVQBumpyq9o4SdEViyrp8s/K3O2knzsV1es1as5yL
>   Fdh4O0Rf8klWv8tb4hYdtGjtvpuETQoYP5vaXgWGqajkvfV++IaYD2FPh4ENF9om
>   3jG+GoAwPNzaxe5RCJResIXuYj0wTig3S8xsJiLmrZC7/bMb8/JmhstoCv7192h3
>   jUg/Ao1Y5iwbp8GYx7h+DQuW81MuXJpaCXPfWSWnHinkqS0SC25v13i7YBSrKUYp
>   tN75WAiX1zLZKAqseS/OIz9luRaxtpL8Ke4u9EWD7ywwSXuOoeNdSnl4Rl5RQ+9P
>   qrNPjlMdoIZTw4h69TIJvbe9og0izgeI+1Jmu0B7B8d/afkn2qKN8e/Vz7wcSPs6
>   tzS7U3yRuAW4wgExZATnNJXINIjuBX/tsvenWqhgofNOSY9wynZgYUUxBL2vzia3
>   o9wWE8J5GI7uTsQzrWrDcuzwV9fZWVbeWKj6lO6p7pn8yvJlZPhsQPyhHAqBOBsP
>   /2DLYjhIOcGi4CnqfVCvf8FZqqjPquol081rRCXaA2A9Q6rlMH1OcqTOBLjt78RL
>   uw8t2YtNxJX3uxsb9jVSznBBltN283ZLPO9IJERXffT+BL86S8hmhLXSkhQPmnRt
>   ijYx6cAJNizLtzJzgrGbjL7o4s3Q8+QFF2rqL3GcdySzdxM61lwVGYJ1MFyJqBCN
>   ibLbz3u+8wovZ5F/0kOt54X4bG7YF31UrlcFam8b4cpHa3vdKJXRfXRwGD82PCWo
>   HDn33MeIkYOdQtBNDkNMl2DF6GcAaD2Z6R4FlS/h+ywW6HggD1OhKPiCu/xn8Ojy
>   WWR3kLiqia0Tdz7dlBFBHxcNQM+1NtiZ9HAU+D71Evyx3R/ezBUrDiHnnZSujk1E
>   Pvh1l5DH0vN788VwDOBjKZRVx7Y7xlWl/oO6wlpLZ/SK0XN+x3jjeReDjnD7FPU/
>   RtBddqgbfMap80VQ+5QXXG4zaJKrkSj3jW4zW+W4+msbMfS5MGzkFLkIHh9i5WCI
>   JYsD31JQOb+rTr/UlCJWBdIC9FSlIKlvMPpHmBB+v853O/SYaBm3Gme3or/xB5y9
>   Y58vK3M9bI9848qkivG2Q2XO+B4URSOTr8GTh8qZKDOYQ12kaWhC3Gc7rxM+N04c
>   6itSVNMX9ohUgLMidLShx5HcWPcdnb396nQCtP0gyDS30ksB6AJzvhVaNTlcyGYy
>   byswfn5fLq+AAI5vBdDiUFjTOX051y/jDKG1B26txgQLo0gCHiQnYYhtHQXe2kev
>   wGSuO2+0v41e9EachmU=
>
> =OL09
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----

### Java code

**BcPGP.java**

```
public class BcPGP {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16; // should always be power of
                                                    // 2
    private static final int KEY_FLAGS = 27;
    private static final int[] MASTER_KEY_CERTIFICATION_TYPES = new int[] { PGPSignature.POSITIVE_CERTIFICATION,
            PGPSignature.CASUAL_CERTIFICATION, PGPSignature.NO_CERTIFICATION, PGPSignature.DEFAULT_CERTIFICATION };

    public static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey(InputStream in) throws IOException, PGPException {

        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection keyRingCollection = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in));

        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for
        // encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //
        PGPPublicKey publicKey = null;

        //
        // iterate through the key rings.
        //
        Iterator rIt = keyRingCollection.getKeyRings();

        while (publicKey == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) rIt.next();
            Iterator kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();
            while (publicKey == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKey key = (PGPPublicKey) kIt.next();
                if (key.isEncryptionKey()) {
                    publicKey = key;
                }
            }
        }

        if (publicKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find public key in the key ring.");
        }
        if (!isForEncryption(publicKey)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("KeyID " + publicKey.getKeyID() + " not flagged for encryption.");
        }

        return publicKey;
    }

    public static PGPSecretKey readSecretKey(InputStream in) throws IOException, PGPException {

        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection keyRingCollection = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in));

        //
        // We just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for
        // signing.
        // In the real world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about
        // this.
        //
        PGPSecretKey secretKey = null;

        Iterator rIt = keyRingCollection.getKeyRings();
        while (secretKey == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPSecretKeyRing keyRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing) rIt.next();
            Iterator kIt = keyRing.getSecretKeys();
            while (secretKey == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPSecretKey key = (PGPSecretKey) kIt.next();
                if (key.isSigningKey()) {
                    secretKey = key;
                }
            }
        }

        // Validate secret key
        if (secretKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find private key in the key ring.");
        }
        if (!secretKey.isSigningKey()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Private key does not allow signing.");
        }
        if (secretKey.getPublicKey().isRevoked()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Private key has been revoked.");
        }
        if (!hasKeyFlags(secretKey.getPublicKey(), KeyFlags.SIGN_DATA)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot be used for signing.");
        }

        return secretKey;
    }

    /**
     * Load a secret key ring collection from keyIn and find the private key
     * corresponding to keyID if it exists.
     *
     * @param keyIn
     *            input stream representing a key ring collection.
     * @param keyID
     *            keyID we want.
     * @param pass
     *            passphrase to decrypt secret key with.
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws PGPException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     */
    public static PGPPrivateKey findPrivateKey(InputStream keyIn, long keyID, char[] pass) throws IOException, PGPException,
            NoSuchProviderException {
        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));
        return findPrivateKey(pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID), pass);

    }

    /**
     * Load a secret key and find the private key in it
     * 
     * @param pgpSecKey
     *            The secret key
     * @param pass
     *            passphrase to decrypt secret key with
     * @return
     * @throws PGPException
     */
    public static PGPPrivateKey findPrivateKey(PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey, char[] pass) throws PGPException {
        if (pgpSecKey == null)
            return null;

        PBESecretKeyDecryptor decryptor = new BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(pass);
        return pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(decryptor);
    }

    /**
     * decrypt the passed in message stream
     */
    public static void decryptFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out, InputStream keyIn, char[] passwd) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
        //
        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        //
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        } else {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }

        //
        // find the secret key
        //
        Iterator it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
        PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;

        while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
            pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) it.next();

            sKey = findPrivateKey(keyIn, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
        }

        if (sKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");
        }

        InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(new BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory(sKey));

        PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

        Object message = plainFact.nextObject();

        if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
            PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
            PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());

            message = pgpFact.nextObject();
        }

        if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
            PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;

            InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
            int ch;

            while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
            throw new PGPException("Encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
        } else {
            throw new PGPException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
        }

        if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected()) {
            if (!pbe.verify()) {
                throw new PGPException("Message failed integrity check");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encryptFile(OutputStream out, InputStream is, PGPPublicKey encKey, boolean armor,
            boolean withIntegrityCheck, int compressType, int encryptType) throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException,
            PGPException {
        System.out.println("Add BouncyCastleProvider");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        if (armor) {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(compressType);

        // setup temp file to hold source data - this is necessary when using
        // PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData which uses a file
        System.out.println("Creating a temp file...");
        File tempfile = File.createTempFile("pgp", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] inBytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = is.read(inBytes)) != -1) {
            fos.write(inBytes, 0, read);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Temp file created at ");
        System.out.println(tempfile.getAbsolutePath());

        PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(comData.open(bOut), PGPLiteralData.BINARY, new File(tempfile.getAbsolutePath()));
        comData.close();

        BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder dataEncryptor = new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(encryptType);
        dataEncryptor.setWithIntegrityPacket(withIntegrityCheck);
        dataEncryptor.setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(dataEncryptor);
        encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey));

        byte[] outBytes = bOut.toByteArray();
        OutputStream cOut = encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, outBytes.length);
        cOut.write(outBytes);
        cOut.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("data encrypted");
    }

    public static void signEncryptFile(OutputStream out, String fileName, PGPPublicKey publicKey, PGPSecretKey secretKey,
            String password, boolean armor, boolean withIntegrityCheck) throws Exception {

        // Initialize Bouncy Castle security provider
        Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);

        if (armor) {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder dataEncryptor = new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES);
        dataEncryptor.setWithIntegrityPacket(withIntegrityCheck);
        dataEncryptor.setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(dataEncryptor);
        encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(publicKey));

        OutputStream encryptedOut = encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, new byte[BcPGP.BUFFER_SIZE]);

        // Initialize compressed data generator
        PGPCompressedDataGenerator compressedDataGenerator = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTags.ZIP);
        OutputStream compressedOut = compressedDataGenerator.open(encryptedOut, new byte[BcPGP.BUFFER_SIZE]);

        // Initialize signature generator
        PGPPrivateKey privateKey = findPrivateKey(secretKey, password.toCharArray());

        PGPContentSignerBuilder signerBuilder = new BcPGPContentSignerBuilder(secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(),
                HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1);

        PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(signerBuilder);
        signatureGenerator.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, privateKey);

        boolean firstTime = true;
        Iterator it = secretKey.getPublicKey().getUserIDs();
        while (it.hasNext() && firstTime) {
            PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
            spGen.setSignerUserID(false, (String) it.next());
            signatureGenerator.setHashedSubpackets(spGen.generate());
            // Exit the loop after the first iteration
            firstTime = false;
        }
        signatureGenerator.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(compressedOut);

        // Initialize literal data generator
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator literalDataGenerator = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream literalOut = literalDataGenerator.open(compressedOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, fileName, new Date(),
                new byte[BcPGP.BUFFER_SIZE]);

        // Main loop - read the "in" stream, compress, encrypt and write to the
        // "out" stream
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] buf = new byte[BcPGP.BUFFER_SIZE];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            literalOut.write(buf, 0, len);
            signatureGenerator.update(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        literalDataGenerator.close();
        // Generate the signature, compress, encrypt and write to the "out"
        // stream
        signatureGenerator.generate().encode(compressedOut);
        compressedDataGenerator.close();
        encryptedDataGenerator.close();
        if (armor) {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // public static boolean verifyFile(InputStream in, InputStream keyIn,
    // String extractContentFile) throws Exception {
    // in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
    //
    // PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
    // PGPCompressedData c1 = (PGPCompressedData) pgpFact.nextObject();
    //
    // pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(c1.getDataStream());
    //
    // PGPOnePassSignatureList p1 = (PGPOnePassSignatureList)
    // pgpFact.nextObject();
    //
    // PGPOnePassSignature ops = p1.get(0);
    //
    // PGPLiteralData p2 = (PGPLiteralData) pgpFact.nextObject();
    //
    // InputStream dIn = p2.getInputStream();
    //
    // IOUtils.copy(dIn, new FileOutputStream(extractContentFile));
    //
    // int ch;
    // PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpRing = new
    // PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));
    //
    // PGPPublicKey key = pgpRing.getPublicKey(ops.getKeyID());
    //
    // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(p2.getFileName());
    //
    // ops.init(new BcPGPContentVerifierBuilderProvider(), key);
    //
    // while ((ch = dIn.read()) >= 0) {
    // ops.update((byte) ch);
    // out.write(ch);
    // }
    //
    // out.close();
    //
    // PGPSignatureList p3 = (PGPSignatureList) pgpFact.nextObject();
    // return ops.verify(p3.get(0));
    // }

    /**
     * From LockBox Lobs PGP Encryption tools.
     * http://www.lockboxlabs.org/content/downloads
     *
     * I didn't think it was worth having to import a 4meg lib for three methods
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isForEncryption(PGPPublicKey key) {
        if (key.getAlgorithm() == PublicKeyAlgorithmTags.RSA_SIGN || key.getAlgorithm() == PublicKeyAlgorithmTags.DSA
                || key.getAlgorithm() == PublicKeyAlgorithmTags.EC || key.getAlgorithm() == PublicKeyAlgorithmTags.ECDSA) {
            return false;
        }

        return hasKeyFlags(key, KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_COMMS | KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_STORAGE);
    }

    /**
     * From LockBox Lobs PGP Encryption tools.
     * http://www.lockboxlabs.org/content/downloads
     *
     * I didn't think it was worth having to import a 4meg lib for three methods
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    private static boolean hasKeyFlags(PGPPublicKey encKey, int keyUsage) {
        if (encKey.isMasterKey()) {
            for (int i = 0; i != BcPGP.MASTER_KEY_CERTIFICATION_TYPES.length; i++) {
                for (Iterator eIt = encKey.getSignaturesOfType(BcPGP.MASTER_KEY_CERTIFICATION_TYPES[i]); eIt.hasNext();) {
                    PGPSignature sig = (PGPSignature) eIt.next();
                    if (!isMatchingUsage(sig, keyUsage)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (Iterator eIt = encKey.getSignaturesOfType(PGPSignature.SUBKEY_BINDING); eIt.hasNext();) {
                PGPSignature sig = (PGPSignature) eIt.next();
                if (!isMatchingUsage(sig, keyUsage)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * From LockBox Lobs PGP Encryption tools.
     * http://www.lockboxlabs.org/content/downloads
     *
     * I didn't think it was worth having to import a 4meg lib for three methods
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    private static boolean isMatchingUsage(PGPSignature sig, int keyUsage) {
        if (sig.hasSubpackets()) {
            PGPSignatureSubpacketVector sv = sig.getHashedSubPackets();
            if (sv.hasSubpacket(BcPGP.KEY_FLAGS)) {
                if ((sv.getKeyFlags() & keyUsage) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**FileCopyPGP**

```
public class FileCopyPGP {
    static final String PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = "D:\\PGP\\public.asc";
    static final String PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "D:\\PGP\\secret.asc";
    static final String PASSWORD = "TestPass12345!";

    static final String SOURCE_PATH = "D:\\PGP\\run\\Source.txt";
    static final String ENCRYPTED_PATH = "D:\\PGP\\run\\Encrypted.txt";
    static final String DECRYPTED_PATH = "D:\\PGP\\run\\Decrypted.txt";

    public static void encrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        try {
            PGPPublicKey encKey = BcPGP.readPublicKey(new FileInputStream(new File(PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)));
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Encryption started");
            BcPGP.encryptFile(os, is, encKey, true, true, CompressionAlgorithmTags.UNCOMPRESSED,
                    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256);
            System.out.println("Encryption ended successfully in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (PGPException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void decrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Decryption started");
            BcPGP.decryptFile(is, os, new FileInputStream(new File(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)), PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            System.out.println("Decryption ended successfully in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        encrypt(new FileInputStream(new File(SOURCE_PATH)), new FileOutputStream(new File(ENCRYPTED_PATH)));
        decrypt(new FileInputStream(new File(ENCRYPTED_PATH)), new FileOutputStream(new File(DECRYPTED_PATH)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You've just compromised your private key. Throw it away. Your question isn't answerable without exhibiting some code.

Comment: Different outputs means different inputs.  Assuming the visible inputs are byte-for-byte the same (check that they are) then the difference is probably in the assumptions/defaults made by the two systems.  Do not rely on defaults anywhere, instead specify them explicitly every time.

Comment: @EJP: encryption code added - no problem for the key. I generated a key pair for this post.

Comment: @rossum: Same input file containing "Hello world!". But it does not matter what the input is, I should be able to decrypt it anyway. The setup given in the post is the one I gathered from the systems configurations.
The idea here is for me to understand why I can't decrypt PI encrypted file and how I can fix it.

Comment: does eclipse and sap pi use the same character encoding? "Hello World" in utf-8 is different from "Hello World" in utf-16

Comment: @k3b: yes. But I do not see why this would influence the decryption to give an empty output?

Comment: An empty output implies some fault in the coding.  First simplify your code down to just encryption and decryption and get that part working.  Then add back in all the other complications, like key generation etc.  You need to split up your code into smaller functional areas to be able to focus on where the problem is.

Comment: @rossum This code is working (cf the fact I can encrypt & decrypt running it in Eclipse). I agree with your statements regarding the best practices for coding or addressing the issue but I'm not sure it's a matter of code here. It's more of the very detailed functioning of PGP or the BouncyCastle library to spot a very particular point that may be environment dependent.

Comment: Have you tried doing this without using compression? The other thing to bare in mind is that close on an ArmoredOutputStream does not actually close the underlying stream. Also I should point out BC is at version 1.52 now.

Comment: @DavidHook It seems it is not a matter of version. I started working on the 1.51 (1.52 was not out at the time) with no luck. It seems I found the solution to the problem. I used v1.45, did not tried a newer library with the new piece of code I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing further research on the subject, I came across this [SCN post](http://scn.sap.com/people/sandeep.maurya4/blog/2011/01/23/pgp-encryptiondecryption-using-java-code). It inspired me to make 3 changes to make it work:

- I used the post code to inspire the one I give above
- I replaced the jar by `bcprov-ext-jdk14-145.jar` and `bcpg-jdk14-145.jar`
- I installed the jar files directly into the java/lib/ext folder - on server level (which requires a bit of PI configuration) - instead of importing them into the repository as IA.

The post mentions putting the key in the imported archive; which means it is difficult to replace if needed, but also to use a different one in each environment (DEV, QA, LIVE...). The code I offer above uses PI value mapping to setup a configurable full file path to the public key in each environment.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTrace;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationConstants;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.value.api.IFIdentifier;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.value.api.IFRequest;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.value.api.IFResponse;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.value.api.XIVMFactory;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.value.api.XIVMService;

public class PGPEncryptor implements StreamTransformation {
    private Map param;
    private AbstractTrace trace;
    private String receiver = null;
    private static final String SOURCE_AGENCY = "YOUR_SOURCE_AGENCY";
    private static final String SOURCE_SCHEME = "YourKeyPath";
    private static final String TARGET_AGENCY = "YOUR_TARGET_AGENCY";
    private static final String TARGET_SCHEME = "YourKeyPath";

    public void setParameter(Map arg0) {
        param = arg0;
        trace = (AbstractTrace) param.get(StreamTransformationConstants.MAPPING_TRACE);
        receiver = (String) param.get(StreamTransformationConstants.RECEIVER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void execute(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws StreamTransformationException {
        try {
            IFIdentifier sourceIdentifier = XIVMFactory.newIdentifier(SOURCE_AGENCY, SOURCE_SCHEME);
            IFIdentifier targetIdentifier = XIVMFactory.newIdentifier(TARGET_AGENCY, TARGET_SCHEME);
            IFRequest request = XIVMFactory.newRequest(sourceIdentifier, targetIdentifier, receiver);
            trace.addInfo("Value Mapping lookup value: " + receiver);
            IFResponse response = XIVMService.executeMapping(request);
            String encKey;
            if (response.hasTargetValues()) {
                encKey = response.getSingleTargetValue();
                trace.addInfo("Using key path: " + encKey);
            } else {
                trace.addInfo("Value Mapping lookup parameters");
                trace.addInfo("Source");
                trace.addInfo("Context: " + sourceIdentifier.getContext() + ", Agency: " + SOURCE_AGENCY + ", Scheme: "
                        + SOURCE_SCHEME);
                trace.addInfo("Target");
                trace.addInfo("Context: " + targetIdentifier.getContext() + ", Agency: " + TARGET_AGENCY + ", Scheme: "
                        + TARGET_SCHEME);
                trace.addInfo("Value: " + receiver);
                throw new StreamTransformationException("Public key not found.");
            }

            // Encrypt the message
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            trace.addInfo("Encryption started");
            new PGPCrypto().encrypt(encKey, in, out, trace);
            trace.addInfo("Encryption ended successfully in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trace.addInfo(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

One important thing to fix in the below class is to use `PGPUtil.getDecoderStream` before creating the `PGPPublicKeyRingCollection`, as described here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/600592/Security/Bouncy-Castle-API-invalid-header

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;

import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTrace;

public class PGPCrypto {

    public void encrypt(String publicKeyPath, InputStream in, OutputStream out, AbstractTrace trace) throws Exception {
        try {
            encrypt(publicKeyPath, inputStreamToString(in), out, trace);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trace.addInfo(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void encrypt(String publicKeyPath, String inString, OutputStream out, AbstractTrace trace) throws Exception {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            InputStream keyStream = new FileInputStream(publicKeyPath);
            // Get Publik key
            PGPPublicKey key = readPublicKeyFromCol(keyStream);
            out = new DataOutputStream(out);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedDataGenerator.ZIP);
            writeStringToLiteralData(comData.open(bOut), inString);
            comData.close();
            // object that encrypts the data
            trace.addInfo("Trace1: Going to encrypt the data");
            PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.CAST5, new SecureRandom(),
                    "BC");
            cPk.addMethod(key);
            byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
            out = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);
            out.write(bytes);
            cPk.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trace.addInfo(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream in) {
        // read in stream into string.
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            // try UTF-8 conversion
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // or atleast in natural encoding
                isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            }
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
                buf.append((char) c);
            }
            in.close();
            isr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private void writeStringToLiteralData(OutputStream out, String inString) throws IOException {
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(out, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, "", inString.length(), new Date());
        pOut.write(inString.getBytes());
        lData.close();
    }

    private PGPPublicKey readPublicKeyFromCol(InputStream in) throws Exception {
        PGPPublicKeyRing pkRing = null;
        PGPPublicKey result = null, key = null;
        try {
            PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pkCol = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in));
            Iterator it = pkCol.getKeyRings();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                pkRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) it.next();
                Iterator pkIt = pkRing.getPublicKeys();
                while (pkIt.hasNext()) {
                    key = (PGPPublicKey) pkIt.next();
                    if (key.isEncryptionKey()) {
                        result = key;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```